# Encrypted disk kernel warning - initramfs image won't boot

Tags: kernel, encryption, initramfs, cryptsetup

After an upgrade to 14.10 on my netbook, I can only manage to boot with the old kernel remaining from the previous 14.04 installation.

For the most recent kernels, I get this warning when they are being updated (i.e. when `update-initramfs` is invoked:

```
WARNING: Option hash missing in crypttab for target sda5_crypt, assuming ripemd160.
         If this is wrong, this initramfs image will not boot.
         Please read /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.initramfs.gz and add
         the correct hash option to your /etc/crytpttab.
cryptsetup: WARNING: target sda5_crypt uses a key file, skipped.
```

And indeed the kernel does not boot. Essentially, it drops to an initramfs shell after issuing this error:

```
ALERT!  /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```

What is strange is that `/etc/crypttab` looks exactly the same (save for the UUID) as in my main computer, where it boots without trouble. Also the old kernel on the netbook manages to boot using the same `/etc/crypttab` the other kernels are failing to boot with.

```
$ cat /etc/crypttab
sda5_crypt UUID=#long string here# none luks
```

Another thing I've noticed: when I boot in recovery mode from the old kernel, on issuing a `sudo reboot`, I also get this warning:

```
/scripts/local-top/cryptroot: line 1: can't open /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: no such file
```

Any ideas on how to bring back the 14.10 kernel to life?

Comment: Just in case anyone runs into this problem and finds this thread, I had the same issue and found that I accidentally used a . (dot) instead of a , (comma) between the options "luks" and "discard". ("luks.discard" instead of "luks,discard") This was the issue.